# Motherboard requires "Processor" which supports Intel HD Graphics Technology

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu

I am interested in the following motherboard ([Intel Hunter Cove DH55HC H55](http://www.ebuyer.com/190367-intel-hunter-cove-dh55hc-h55-socket-1156-dvi-vga-hdmi-out-8-boxdh55hc)), which seems to have a DVI, HDMI, and VGA port on the motherboard but it requires a "Processor" with Intel HD Graphics Technology.

What does that mean?  Does that mean the CPU needs to support Intel HD Graphics Technology, or the GPU needs to support Intel HD Graphics Technology?

Comment: Note that with the current second genernation of Intel Core i processors you'll only be able to use 2 of the on board/cpu graphics ports at once.

Comment: What if I added a PCI-e x16 graphics card which has 2 dvi ports, does that mean I can connect 2 monitors to the motherboard and 2 monitors to the graphics card giving me a large desktop across 4 monitors?

Comment: Yes, they're independent of one another, I've found some issues with Windows 7 deciding "your graphics are running slowly, we've switched you to non aero mode", which people are generally blaming the graphics drivers for. I have 5 monitors on mine, 2 on Intel, 3 on AMD graphics card (one needs to be displayport)

Comment: please could you tell me which motherboard and AMD graphics card you currently have?

Comment: ASROCK SKT-1155 Z68 PRO3 and ASUS 1GB RADEON HD 6670

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the specifications mention:

> - Onboard graphics Requires Processor with Intel HD Graphics, currently I3-530/540 and I5-670/661/660/650 Processors

You'll need these processors to make use of the IGP. There's no such thing as a "GPU which supports Intel HD Graphics Technology", it features a PCI-Express x16 slot, so you can always add GPU

Comment: So if I get a i3-560 and a GT 430 GPU which has 2 dvi ports, I can connect 4 monitors giving me a large desktop spanning all 4 monitors?

Comment: @oshirowanen - One would normally disable the onboard graphics card once they install a PCIE Graphics Card.  You want to pick up a graphics card with additional ports, or have multiple graphic cards and connect them in serial, to have multiple ports.

Comment: @Ramhound, I just wanted to know if I added a pcie gpu and left the onboard graphics on, would I be able to connect 4 monitors?

Answer (score 2):

It means that you need to use a processor with an integrated graphic card to make use of the motherboard’s DVI, HDMI and VGA ports.

Answer (score 1):

It means you'll have to use a [LGA 1156](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1156) [compatible processor](http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?BoardName=DH55HC). Some have an Intel HD Graphics iGPU, others don't, so no, this motherboard *does not require* Intel HD Graphics.